# How to view VR/360 photos from website in VR headset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, virtual-reality

I'm building a feature on a website which allows users to upload and share their VR Images taken using 360 cameras.

I've managed to find a nice little script which allows viewing of 360 photos in the web browser:

http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/

What i'm trying to do now is provide a way for users with VR headsets to view the images in their headset so when they rotate their head, the image responds.

Does anyone know of some code or plugin which might be able to provide this facility?

**UPDATE:**

Google VR View reads as if it potentially provides this facility:

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/vrview

However, the only example I have found doesn't appear to transfer VR view on the web to a headset/cardboard setup:

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/03/introducing-vr-view-embed-immersive.html

Comment: Hey! Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @TheUnreal Nope.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Threejs-VR](https://github.com/charliegerard/Threejs-VR).
Specifically, in [js/OrbitControls.js](https://github.com/charliegerard/Threejs-VR/blob/master/js/OrbitControls.js) you can find methods to detect VR movements; for example: `getPolarAngle`, `getAzimuthalAngle`, `rotateLeft`, `rotateUp`, `panLeft`, ...).
Also, check this nice blog post: [Virtual-Reality-ThreeJs](http://charliegerard.github.io/blog/Virtual-Reality-ThreeJs/)